# VBA Excel Convert String Array element to Long "Type Mismatch"

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, type-mismatch

so I have a simple problem that I'm trying to solve. I have a column of numbers that I'm reading in as a string. I'm then wanting to convert the string to a Long and store that in an array that is of type Long.

I tried this initially:

```
ElseIf stArray(0, i) = "SrcWth" Then
        Debug.Print "Found the Width Column"
        For j = 0 To UBound(stArray)
            whArray(0, j) = CLng(stArray(j, i))
        Next j
```

stArray is the 2d array that is holding the CSV file info. It is type String.
whArray is the 2d array that is going to hold the two columns of numbers that I want. However, it complains about the type mismatch.

I then thought maybe it was seeing some whitespace, so I tried trimming it.

```
ElseIf stArray(0, i) = "SrcWth" Then
        Debug.Print "Found the Width Column"
        For j = 0 To UBound(stArray)
            whArray(0, j) = CLng(Trim(stArray(j, i)))
        Next j
```

It made no difference.
What am I doing wrong? I imagine it's having a problem with the CLng, so I'm not sure.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The very first thing you pass to `CLng` is `"SrcWth"`.

I imagine this is the column header so you want to start your next loop at 1

```
For j = 1 To UBound(stArray, 1)
    whArray(0, j) = CLng(Trim(stArray(j, i)))
Next j
```

You also could include a check if it's a numeric string

```
For j = 1 To UBound(stArray, 1)
    If Not isNumeric(Trim(stArray(j, i))) Then
        MsgBox "invalid value: """ & Trim(stArray(j, i)) & """ at position " & j & ", " & i
    Else
        whArray(0, j) = CLng(Trim(stArray(j, i)))
    End If
Next j
```

---

Edit: as it turns out the array contained empty strings because it was initialized too big for the data. Trying to convert an empty string with `CLng` will return a type mismatch as well.

Comment: Yes, that was a mistake which I corrected at your suggestion. But I get the same error at the same line.

Comment: did you check what you are passing to `CLng` when the error appears using the debugger?

Comment: I tried out your if-statement. It appears that I'm trying to pass nothing, which would give a type-mismatch. That's weird. There is definitely data in the array because I can print out everything just fine as a string.

Comment: Shoot, I know the problem. It's the size of the array. I made it larger than it needs to be, so it's reading in all that whitespace. 
I don't have my arrays as being dynamic, something I don't know how to do yet, so that's the problem.

Comment: Ah I see. I will add that to the answer in case anyone stumbles upon this.

Comment: Thanks for your help!